# spring-boot - running junit test with two servers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I created with java spring-boot a server (“node”). There are a few instance of nodes, as the difference is by a configuration file for every node. For example:

node1.properties:

```
application.name=FullNode
receiving.server.addresses=tcp://localhost:8001
propagation.server.addresses=tcp://localhost:8002
recovery.server.address=http://localhost:8060
....
```

node 2.properties:

```
application.name=FullNode
receiving.server.addresses=tcp://localhost:6001
propagation.server.addresses=tcp://localhost:6002
recovery.server.address=http://localhost:8050

...
```

To test the process of sending data to the server, I wrote a JUnit test for the TransactionController.

TransactionController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/transaction")
public class TransactionController {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionService transactionService;
    ...

    @RequestMapping(method = PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<Response> addTransaction(@Valid @RequestBody 
             AddTransactionRequest addTransactionRequest) {
        return transactionService.addNewTransaction(addTransactionRequest);
    }
...
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DBTests {
    @Autowired
    private TransactionController transactionController;

    @Test
    public void addTransaction() {
        transactionController.addTransaction(transactionRequest);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that every node also sends his transactions to the other nodes. But How I could test it with JUnit? I could not just create in the test two instance of a TransactionController, because TransactionController is a spring bean singleton, and the only way to run a node, is with his configuration file.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Mockito framework. Mocking out the `TransactionService`. Instead of firing up 2 servers which lends itself to be more of an integration test instead of a unit test.